# Adding a duplicate of Bootstrap as a starting point for customization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been doing research on best practices for customizing bootstrap. I get the impression that the best (css only) practice is to add a style sheet after bootstrap is called and override bootstrap classes as you customize. This being the case it seems like a reasonable starting point would be to add a duplicate of the bootstrap stylesheet and modify it's values while leaving the class names the same.

I'm hoping to get some feed back on this approach before I commit to it.

Comment: For the first step that's ok. You could also modify less/sass/scss of bootstrap (from which its css is generated). You can also take a look at fontawesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/.

Comment: If one were to modify the less/sass/scss is it still advisable to only alter the values and not the class names?

Comment: I think yes in most cases. In fact, you can check Bootstrap javascript code. It is only ~2000 lines long and if class name is used there - you probably shouldn't change it.

Comment: I think adding in a duplicate would be extra bloat you don't need.  The minimized CSS file is still 115KB, so to have two CSS files of that size would be overkill. My suggestion would be to only have the  styles you want to override in that custom style sheet.  And yes, only alter the values and not the class name.  The JS often times queues off the class name, so if you alter that you may lose some functionality in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I infact do this, twitter invested 1000's of man hours into its development and it can save you time getting a project off the ground, quickly.

Most people and projects I have seen have bootstrap, then use a second stylesheet to override the default rules.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea only to copy over the styles you are using, as including a full stylesheet with redundant classes will effect performance. Not much but every little helps.